# Появляются прерывания при выводе кадров, как исправить?

Tags: c++

Когда пытаюсь вывести готовую анимацию в терминал, получаются прерывания.
[Видео](https://vimeo.com/661216590).

Сам код основного цикла

```cpp
for (int t = 0; t < 10000; t++){
        vector3 light = norm(vector3(-0.5, 0.5, -1.0));
        vector3 spherePos = vector3(0, 3, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++){
                vector2 uv = vector2(i, j) / vector2(width, height) * 2.0f - 1.0f;
                uv.x *= aspect * pixelAspect;
                vector3 ro = vector3(-5, 0, 0);
                vector3 rd = norm(vector3(2, uv));

                ro = rotateY(ro, 0.25);
                rd = rotateY(rd, 0.25);
                ro = rotateZ(ro, t * 0.01);
                rd = rotateZ(rd, t * 0.01);

                vector3 boxN = 0;
                float diff = 1;
                for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                    float minIt = 99999;
                    vector2 intersection = sphere(ro - spherePos, rd, 1);
                    vector3 n = 0;
                    float albedo = 1;
                    if (intersection.x > 0) {
                        vector3 itPoint = ro - spherePos + rd * intersection.x;
                        minIt = intersection.x;
                        n = norm(itPoint);
                    }
                    vector3 boxN = 0;
                    intersection = box(ro, rd, 1, boxN);
                    if (intersection.x > 0 && intersection.x < minIt) {
                        minIt = intersection.x;
                        n = boxN;
                    }
                    intersection = plane(ro, rd, vector3(0, 0, -1), 1);
                    if (intersection.x > 0 && intersection.x < minIt) {
                        minIt = intersection.x;
                        n = vector3(0, 0, -1);
                        albedo = 0.5;
                    }
                    if (minIt < 99999) {
                        diff *= (dot(n, light) * 0.5 + 0.5) * albedo;
                        ro = ro + rd * (minIt - 0.01);
                        rd = reflect(rd, n);
                    }
                    else break;
                }
                //uv.x += sin(t * 0.001);
                int color = (int)(diff * 20);
                color = clamp(color, 0, gradientSize);
                char pixel = gradient[color];
                screen[i + j * width] = pixel;
                
            }
        }
        printf("%s", screen);
    }
```

Comment: Что за бредовые вопросы (от гугла?) при  переходе  по вашей ссылке?

Comment: Не знаю, залил на Vimeo, одна из самых популярных видеоплатформ.

Answer (score 0):

Тут не используется `flush` во время вывода, в итоге пришлось заменить

```cpp
        printf("%s", screen);
```

на

```cpp
        std::cout << screen << std::flush;
```

Comment: А в чем проблема была его вызвать?? `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: Ни в чём) Просто решил так